# how to stop s3fs from deleting files added to a mounted S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

Can s3fs-fuse be configured to synchronize the Linux filesystem [Amazon 2 EC2] to match what is in a mounted S3 Bucket..?

It appears to do the opposite, files added to S3 via the console are being deleted from S3, often on the hour.

S3 Logs show delete request coming from the IAM user used to set up s3fs.

I have tried rebuilding the bucket and the EC2 Instance with basic/default settings.

Here is the mount command:

```
sudo s3fs my-s3-bucket -o use_cache=/tmp -o allow_other -o uid=1000 -o mp_umask=002 -o multireq_max=5 /var/www/html/call-lib/lib -o nonempty"
```

Comment: Rather than using `s3fs`, have you considered using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? It has a `aws s3 sync` command that can work in either direction.

Comment: Yes, this was a much better way, thanks.  Note the --delete switch is needed to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

s3fs does not synchronize a folder with a bucket; instead it provides a view into that bucket and allows modifications of objects.  Further s3fs does not automatically delete objects unless your application deletes them.  If you want to synchronize a folder look at [rclone](https://rclone.org/).

Comment: This makes sense, will try rclone, looks like an implementation of rsynch which is a great tool.